# how do create ImageView left of TextView?

Tags: android

i follow this tutorial which show tab bar like googleplay http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html  but how to i add  different activities on each tab bar?  like myactivity1.java,  myactivity2.java,  myactivity3.java?? please help me where i place this???

```
      @Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);

SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this, 
 getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: You need to use Fragments (as the 'child windows') and FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: full sourc code is here   http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSwipeyTabsSample


just tell me in which palce i add activities

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
                    SwipeyTabsAdapter {

            private final Context mContext;

            public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                    this.mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return TITLES.length;
            }

            public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                                    R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
                    view.setText(TITLES[position]);
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                            }
                    });

                    return view;
            }

    }
```

To:

```
private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
                    SwipeyTabsAdapter {

            private final Context mContext;

            public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                    this.mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0: //If the position is 0, the SwipeyTabFragment will be shown, do this for each fragment.
                SwipeyTabFragment frag = new SwipeyTabFragment();
                return frag;
        }
        return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return TITLES.length;
            }

            public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                                    R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
                    view.setText(TITLES[position]);
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                            }
                    });

                    return view;
            }

    }
```

Comment: I believe you meant Fragment references. The Fragment references come in the 'switch' part I have written under getItem(position) function.